# How to use Next.js ISR revalidation with react-query hydration?

Tags: next.js, react-query, tanstackreact-query

Hello stackoverflow community  I have a Next.js (v13.3.4) project in which I use ISR with react-query (v4.29.5) hydration on some pages. The behaviour of my solution is not working as expected  - the user keeps seeing initial static HTML data even after revalidation and getting updated data. Next.js returns updated static HTML data only after a hard refresh (CMD + R) in the browser.

Here is my `getStaticProps` method:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  await queryClient.prefetchInfiniteQuery(
    [QueryKeys.cookbooks],
    ({ pageParam = 1 }) => cookbookService(axiosInstance).getCookbooks({ pageParam, limit: 20 }),
    { getNextPageParam }
  );

  return {
    props: {
      dehydratedState: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dehydrate(queryClient))),
    },
    revalidate: 10, // 10 seconds
  };
};
```

For easier explanation purposes I set the `revalidate` value to 10 (10 seconds), react-query staleTime to 60 * 1000 (10 seconds) and cacheTime to 5 minutes.

**This is how I expect things to work:**

1. When a user visits this page for the first time, Next.js generates a static HTML page with the initial data based on the `getStaticProps` function. In your case, this initial data is fetched using React Query's prefetchInfiniteQuery.
2. The revalidate option is set to 10 seconds. This means that after the initial generation, if a user visits the page again within 10 seconds, they will see the statically generated page with the initial data without making a new server request. This provides a fast initial load time.
3. After the 10-second period has passed since the last generation, if a user visits the page again, Next.js will trigger a revalidation process. During this process, it will re-run the `getStaticProps` function to fetch the latest data.
4. While the revalidation process is ongoing, the page will still display the static HTML with the initial data. This ensures that users see something on the page immediately, even if the data is not yet updated.
5. Once the revalidation process is complete, Next.js will replace the static page with the new version that includes the updated data fetched in `getStaticProps`.
6. After the first revalidation process, the page is updated with the latest data fetched at that time.
7. If the user closes and reopens the page within the 10-second window, Next.js will serve the static HTML generated during the first revalidation process, which includes the updated data.

**Actual Behaviour:**

- In Step 7 the user is shown the **initial data** as static HTML **and not the updated one**. However the data gets replaced by the updated data after a short delay. This happens even if I open a completely new browser window and switch between browsers.
- Only after doing a hard refresh in the browser (CMD + R) does the Next.js actually show the updated data as static HTML when the user re-opens the page again. Until then I only get the initial data as static HTML.

Do you guys have any idea why this is happening?